# Use checkbox value in search query

Tags: content-search-web-part

I'm using Content By Search WebPart to list Announcements from different site collections.

By using below query I'm able to show announcement items from different site collections.

```
path:"http://spdev:XXXX/sites"  ("STS_ListItem_Announcements")
```

In my announcement following field present:

```
Title        Single line of Text

Department   Single line of Text

Body         Multi line of Text

Global       Check Box
```

My requirement is to show only Announcement item which Global as `Yes`.
(If I tick the value it show in list as "Yes" if i not selected it show as "NO" ) b

By using below query I'm able to select announcement which are related to Department `Admin`

```
path:"http://spdev:xxxx/sites"  ("STS_ListItem_Announcements") Admin
```

If I enter `Yes` in the query no result is retrieved.

```
path:"http://spdev:xxxx/sites"  ("STS_ListItem_Announcements") Yes
```

How to use checkbox value in query string?

Comment: I guess you didn´t even think of reading Microsofts Explanation for the KQL-Syntax?? (KQL stands for Keyword-Query-Language).

Answer (score 1):

First of all always good to avoid hard coded urls, so instead you can use `Path:{SiteCollection.URL}`  or `Path:{Site.URL}` depending on your need.

Now if your `Global` field is a site column , then there will be a managed property created by the name `GlobalOWSBOOL` . You can go to Search Schema and check if it exists otherwise you can create a new managed property and map it to this column and make it searchable and queryable.
So once you have it ready your final query should look like something below:

```
Path:{SiteCollection.URL} AND ContentType:0x0104* AND GlobalOWSBOOL=1
```

Note:`0x0104*` is for all announcements.

Comment: ContentType:0x0104* Not working for me